# Why is my shadow pass not transparent?

Tags: rendering

My shadow pass has a black background and I don't know why. I've tried using different lights and I still have the same issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have the following setup:

- Renderer: Cycles
- Film: transparent
- Light: Area

[image]

Here's my compositor:
[image]

My view:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your .blend file so we can see what the issue is?

Comment: Thanks @Lowlande52, the issue has already been resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadow pass is made with black and white image, Alpha is a different Pass, like Shadow pass, that's why you don't have transparent included.Shadow pass is often applied with the blend mode multiply to highllight the shadow on top of an image. You don't need it but if you want a shadow pass to have transparency. you could apply the alpha from the original image with a set alpha node to your shadow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that alpha (`RGBA`) is selected in render output

[image]

Comment: The setting is already on, thanks anyway!